# downloading directory and its contents

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the following to download a file:

```
window.location.href = 'some_url.php';
```

and the php looks like this:

```
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$_GET['filename'].'"');        
readfile('../../students/'.$_GET['filename']);
```

this is working fine. However, I would like to understand what is going on here. (how is that the file is dowloaded). Also, how can I download a directory (currently this code get to download a file, but how could I download a directory, it could be as .zip or .rar as well

Comment: Together with a recursive iterator iterator and ZipArchive, you can achieve this easily enough.

Comment: I understand that. I understand that I can read all the files in the directory. However, how do I create the folder that will contain all these files. I am no sure how to go about it. Would you mind showing me how!

Comment: If you do an iterator and it gives you a path like `what/ever/file/is/here.php`, the ZipArchive should create those directories accordingly inside the zip file.

Comment: I don't think I get you still, but thanks for replying!

Comment: Here is a class that may help you that I have made for this purpose: https://github.com/rasclatt/ZipEngine  You can modify as you see fit